# Maven Release Plugin Pushing Tags To Wrong Repo

Tags: java, git, maven, version-control, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to execute a mvn release:prepare on my project and it runs up until the very end where it tries to commit the tag then it fails:

```
[INFO] Tagging release with the label v1.8.0...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/terraframe/Documents/workspace/Runway-SDK && git tag -F /var/folders/tY/tY5PnSNPED0Yr7FtapST2++++TI/-Tmp-/maven-scm-864030210.commit v1.8.0
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/terraframe/Documents/workspace/Runway-SDK
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/terraframe/Documents/workspace/Runway-SDK && git push ssh://git@github.com/terraframe v1.8.0

...

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project runwaysdk-main: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] ERROR: Repository not found.
[ERROR] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The specific git command that fails is:

`git push ssh://git@github.com/terraframe v1.8.0`

Here's my scm definition in my runwaysdk-main pom:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/terraframe/Runway-SDK.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/terraframe/Runway-SDK.git</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/terraframe/Runway-SDK.git</url>
</scm>
```

tldr: My repo url is defined as `scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/terraframe/Runway-SDK.git`
Yet this git push command is trying to push to `ssh://git@github.com/terraframe`.

Why? And how do I fix it?

**Edit:**

I am executing this on a parent pom (runwaysdk-main) of a multi-module with a flat project structure:

```
github.com/terraframe/Runway-SDK
  /runwaysdk-main
  /runwaysdk-common
  /runwaysdk-client
  /runwaysdk-server
```

I am using the latest version of the maven-release-plugin, 2.4.1.

Comment: What version of the release plugin are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-709. As a workaround, you could use version 2.3.2 of the maven-release-plugin

Comment: I solved the problem by following this guys advice: http://warpedjavaguy.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/how-i-defeated-the-maven-release-plugin-in-a-flat-structured-multi-module-project/

Essentially he says to use 2 separate poms. 1 as a parent inhertiance pom that contains most of the info (in a flat structure), and 1 as a root pom at the root of the repo which only contains the modules list.

Comment: We are using similar structure, but failed. I have tried maven-release-plugin 2.5 and 2.5.3, both failed.